# ICollectionView.Filter Property for Hashtable

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, collectionviewsource

I have a DataGrid which is bound to a Hashtable, I would love to filter it, depending on the text entered in the textbox it should search the key of the Hashtable and show the result(entire data row which belongs to it).

```
//GridView
var data = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(wordListView.ItemsSource);
//TextBox which contains the search term
data.Filter = (wert) => wert.ToString().Contains(textBoxSearch.Text);
```

At the moment when I type someting in a textbox it will show nothing, it will remove the entire data in that Gridview.

What to do here ?

**Updated**
The 'System.Collections.Hashtable' has a key which contains escaped file paths and the value is the file name.

Comment: What does your Hashtable contain? i.e. what is the **type** of the key and the value? And to be sure, it's a `Hashtable` class, not `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`?

Comment: udated my answer :)( key and value are strings, 'Hashtable hsh = new Hashtable();'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `wordListView.ItemsSource` is a `System.Collections.Hashtable`. Then what the filter method receives should be a [DictionaryEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry(v=vs.110).aspx) instance, so you can use something like this

```
data.Filter = (entry) => ((DictionaryEntry)entry).Key.ToString().Contains(textBoxSearch.Text);
```